# Android - Imageview from URL

Tags: android, url, imageview

I am trying to download the picture from the following URL. There is not filename to it and according to the web developer it is dumping binary data. How do I get the data and convert it to bitmap and set it to the imageview.

http://mobile.test.com/member/17/profile_picture

The following code is what I have use and it only with URL contain the file name.

```
private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String urlString) throws IOException {
    InputStream in = null;
    int response = -1;

    URL url = new URL(urlString);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

    if (!(conn instanceof HttpURLConnection))
        throw new IOException("Not an HTTP connection");

    try {
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) conn;
        httpConn.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        httpConn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.connect();
        response = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (response == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw new IOException("Error connecting");
    }
    return in;
}

private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
        bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Comment: i m not clear which image from the url , the above url u posted redirct me to http://www.test.com/

Comment: apologize to mention that the url i give was just a sample, the actual url required log in to see it. My app is able to do the log in. after I have login and the homepage only return JSON and one of the data is an url to the profile picture. The url to the picture does not has a filename to it but if i try on a browser it will show the image.

Comment: "The url to the picture does not has a filename" I didnt got this statement ? if possible can u share the url via mail so that i can help you

Comment: I have send an email to you. Instruction on how to access the image is stated in the email. CHeers